# How to convert a source c files to corresponding .o files using suffix rule in makefile?

Tags: makefile

Suppose we have a.c b.c c.c .So the make file will like this

```
app:  a.o b.o c.o 
    gcc  -o app.o a.o b.o c.o

a.o:   a.c
    gcc  -c  a.c

b.o:    b.c
    gcc  -c  b.c

c.o:   c.c
    gcc -c c.c
```

In the future more C files may be added. So do I need to make target of `.o` extensions for each `.c` file. I got to know about `suffix rules` which uses the .source-extension.target-extension. But I could understand how to use this suffix rule in the make file. Please provide me the command to be included in make file and please describe the syntax.I am newbie to makefile.

Comment: make already has a built-in rule for that step, you don't need to add anything for it. Technically, you don't even need a makefile at all for that rule to work.

Comment: http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html has good explanation and example of what you want to do. Not sure if SO guidelines allow me to post the answer verbatim from the site hence adding as comment. Check the -- Another makefile (using makedepend and more advanced make syntax) -- section on that page.

Comment: @Etan Resinser:What is that step??

Comment: The `.c` to `.o` step. Try this: `mkdir maketest; cd maketest; touch foo.c; make foo.o` and see what you get from make. You don't need the `.c` to `.o` rules at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below makefile.

```
app:  a.o b.o c.o 
    gcc -o $@ $^

a.o : a.h
b.o : b.h
c.o : c.h

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<
```

Where `$@` is the `target(app)`, `$^` is the list of dependencies and `$<` is the corresponding `c` file to compile to `object` file

Comment: thankx bro.But suppose that a.c depends upon header p.h and b.c depends on q.h.if we change the headers file then according to your command dependency of a.o is on only a.c which is not correct.In that case how could we write yours command by modifying it

Comment: thankx.I understood.But if I write %.o:[Tab]%.c  after the dependecies of .o on .h Then how I would the 'make' execute the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample makefile for compiling `c` code.

```
TARGET = a.out
SRCS = a.c b.c c.c
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS = -g -ggdb -O2 -Wall -Werror

CC = gcc
RM = rm

.PHONY: all clean

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```